# Open array with other array

Tags: java, arrays

I don't really now how to describe it properly, but I'll try/

I have a 2D integer array in Java. Now I want to write something at a position.
Normally I would need to do `array[a][b]=x;`.

I also have an array `z` with two values `{a,b}` is there a way that I can simplify writing that `x` value there?

At the moment I am doing it like this: `array[z[0]][z[1]] = x` but is there a simpler method?

Comment: you mean like `array[z[0]][z[1]] = x`? doesn't look simpler to me...

Comment: Do you mean `array[z[0]][z[1]] = x` ? But `z` should not be an array if it always has two elements, and each plays a special role. Maybe use `java.awt.Point`?

Comment: This is what I am doing right now, I thought that there probably would be a simpler method so that I can open a array with a other one.

Comment: Not sure if that counts as simpler, but often you can use an index-mapped 1d array instead of a 2d-array. Then it becomes `array[x + width * y]`

Comment: @Thilo unfortunately the array is given to me like that and I can't change it :(

Comment: Well, the direct answer is: No. You have to write it like this. No special shortcut syntax to deep-index into a multi-dimensional array using an index path.

Comment: Everything becomes clearer when you start encapsulating your data structures into objects: matrix.setValueAt(coordinates, value). Matrix would encapsulate your 2D array, Coordinates would be an immutable class containing an x and an y fields.

Comment: There is no special syntax available but you can write a method `public static void set(int[][] arr, int[] posArr, int i) { arr[posArr[0]][posArr[1]] = i; }` and use it like this `set(arr, posArr, 10);` (if you think this reduces the amount of typing)

Answer (score 1):

write a class to contain your array and access it's elements with a getter and a setter.

```
public static class Array2D {
    private int[][] array;

    public Array2D(int x, int y) {
        array = new int[x][y];
    }

    public int get(int[] index) {
        return array[index[0]][index[1]];
    }

    public void set(int[] index, int val) {
        array[index[0]][index[1]] = val;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Array2D array = new Array2D(2, 8);
    int[] coords = { 1, 5 };
    array.set(coords, 5);
    System.out.println(array.get(coords));
}
```